# Cannot find the server side value when __scraping__ a website

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, web-scraping

Hello I want to **scrape** a weather website which is https://www.theweathernetwork.com/. I write below code to get live weather but didn't get any value in my code.

input

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


html_page = requests.get("https://www.theweathernetwork.com/bd/weather/dhaka/dhaka")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page.content, 'lxml')

content=soup.find(class_='wx-content current-obs')

temp=content.find('span', class_='temp')

temp
```

output

```
[<span>°</span>]
```

Comment: where do you see `wx-content current-obs` on the page?

Comment: Please search this in inspect element area.

Comment: I'm looking at the page you have linked in English language, and there is no `wx-content` in the whole document

Comment: Did you go to on https://www.theweathernetwork.com/bd/weather/dhaka/dhaka this link?